# Mapbox framework not found error in XCode

Tags: xcode, runtime-error, mapbox, xcode11.4

I'm working with an API called Mapbox. I'm not sure if this is the right place to even post this so if it's not, I apologize. Working in XCode, I've added Mapbox.framework.dSYM and Mapbox.framework to the Frameworks folder in the project. I followed the steps on their installation for "Downloads" @ https://www.mapbox.com/install/ios/ and it just doesn't work. When I clean and try to run the project, I get an error that says "framework not found Mapbox", implying that Mapbox wasn't in the frameworks. Anyone have any experience with Mapbox or XCode? I'm very new to both. Thank you so much in advance.

Best.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using the downloads method, unzip the zip file and copy the two framework files (ending in .framework) to the Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded content section under Project > General.

Make sure to add the `bash "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH}/Mapbox.framework/strip-frameworks.sh"`to Target > build phases > + (add run script) and ensure that `run script only when installing` is selected.

An easier way to incorporate the Mapbox SDK into your XCode project may be using the [Coacoapods method](https://www.mapbox.com/install/ios/cocoapods/).